# No rational Solutions of $x^3+y^3+z^3$

Tags: number-theory, polynomials

I want to find a '$c$' such that $c$ $\in \mathbb{Q}$ and  $x^3+y^3+z^3=c$ has no solutions over rationals.

Comment: What about $\pi$?

Comment: @baharampuri It is not a Rational number

Comment: Oh i see, $c \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: There is no such $c\in\Bbb Q$, see here http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=%2FPEM%2FPEM2_2_02%2FS0013091500007604a.pdf&code=8b04576f94a942e5d69390f92ddf4fcd

Comment: Does $c=0$ work for you? The only solutions of $x^3+y^3+z^3=0$ are the trivial ones. This equivalent to the Fermat equation $x^3+y^3=(-z)^3$.

Comment: @lhf No It wont work as Firstly (0,0,0) is a solution and Secondly Fermats Last theorem talks about Non zero Integer solutions